# Bash - unexpected token `fi'

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have a problem while comparing two strings in IF statement.

```
if [ $users -eq $usersFinal ] ; than 
    echo "Well done!"
fi
```

I get an unexpected token `fi' error and really don't see what's wrong in the syntax.

Comment: You need then not than.

Comment: thx guys on that (i feel so bad), but that is not the only problem

Comment: @TranceFusion: What are the other problems?

Comment: still the same error

Comment: Do you have any else if, or else statements after this if because if you do the fi needs to go at the end of all the statements

Comment: this one is the only IF in the whole script

Comment: Try surrounding `$users` and `$usersFinal` with double quotes.

Comment: did it like `if [ "$users" -eq "$usersFinal" ] ; then
 echo "Bravo!!!!!!!!!"
fi` but still the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were still missing a ; in your one liner.

```
users=9
usersFinal=9

if [ "$users" -eq "$usersFinal" ];then 
    echo "Bravoidididid!"
fi
```

Your oneliner:

```
users=9;usersFinal=9;if [ "$users" -eq "$usersFinal" ] ; then echo "Bravoidididid!" fi
```

is missing the last ;

```
users=9;usersFinal=9;if [ "$users" -eq "$usersFinal" ] ; then echo "Bravoidididid!"; fi
```

I'm assuming that users and usersFinal are integers, not strings.

For a oneliner, the ; go after the if test ( before the then ), and before the fi.

If users / usersFinal are strings, use ==

```
users='fred';usersFinal='fred';if [ "$users" == "$usersFinal" ] ; then echo "Bravoidididid!"; fi

users='fred george'
usersFinal='fred george'

if [ "$users" == "$usersFinal" ];then 
    echo "Bravoidididid!"
fi
```

Note that quoting the variables becomes important here with strings. With single bracket's it's necessary to avoid error if one of the variables is empty.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

-gt, -lt, -eq, -le, -ge are integer comparison operators.

Note that you will see examples with "$x" = "$y", that is, a single =, but I find it much more clear and easy to read to be explicit and use == always for string comparison in Bash (note also the subtle differences with = and == with [[ ]]).

Note in particular on that page when you use > and when -gt. Easy way to remember it: [[ $a > $b ]] but [ "$a" -gt "$b" ] (single versus double brackets).

Comment: in last post i commented that users and usersFinal are strings, anything different then?